# asp.net webapi token authentication

Tags: asp.net, angular, token, owin, webapi

I having 3 existing WEB API which already has OWIN token based authentication connecting to 3 different databases (userid and pwd is different). I want to create an application which uses these 3 web APIs based on a single login. How to achieve this? Any source code to share.

- Api_1  --> DB1
- Api_2  --> DB2
- Api_3  --> DB3

New App (angular) --> Consumes above THREE WEB APIs .

Need your advise on this

Comment: All of these web apis will need one place to check tokens are valid. There are multiple ways to achieve this and also existing 3rd party services. there are too many opened questions in your question

Comment: These APi already consuming by different systems. So I cant change place to check token validity. I dont want to change the token checking in these existing API

Comment: do you want to do this integration on frontend? or you want to create 4th webAPI kind of like facade with own your login? and then use this in your front-end app